# How to set close unselected node in JsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

How to close unselected node? right now all node is open. is it possible to open for selected node only?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "variant": "large",
                    "icons": false,
                },
                "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json),
            },
            "checkbox": {
                "keep_selected_style": false,
            },
            "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "sort"],
        });
    });
```

[Image below is how its look. Negeri Sembilan & Pahang should be close coz non of it is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiZXH.png)

Comment: why do you use `C#` and `ASP.Net-MVC` tags here? Also, images of code are [always useless](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: sorry, im new here. i dont really know how to use this platform. how can i share the image actually?

Comment: It's ok, just read the link I posted. If it is an image of code - just copy/retype this code as text. If it is an image of UI - add some description (like: _"Here is how my UI looks like: [Image]"_). If it is an image of a HTML page - add a HTML code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "variant": "large",
                    "icons": false,
                },
                "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json),
            },
            "checkbox": {
                "keep_selected_style": false,
                "tie_selection": false
            },
            "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "sort"],
        }).bind("check_node.jstree", function (e, data) {

            closeNode();
        });
    });


    function closeNode() {
        $('#jstree li').each(function (index, value) {
            var node = $("#jstree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
            if (!node.state.checked && node.state.opened) {
                $("#jstree").jstree('close_node', node);
            }
        });
    }
```